# E-olymp:Restaurants. Only partially accepted

Tags: c++

This is the problem: [Restaurant](https://www.e-olymp.com/en/problems/8351)

> In a certain city there is a restaurant network that has a total of n almost identical halls. The administration received k applications for holding corporate events on a pre-holiday day. Each application specifies the start and end time (from 00:00 to 23:59). To carry out one event, one hall is needed entirety (which specifically does not matter). After the end of the event, you need at least half an hour to prepare for the next event in this room. It is required to satisfy as many applications as possible. If you can satisfy all, then the smallest number of halls should be used.

I tried to solve it this way, first I sorted each application based on their start time, from earliest to latest, then if if they have same start time, I sorted them based on their finish time, from earliest to latest. Then I iterated through every application, for each application I checked if there was a free hall. But I only got 92% accepted.

here is my code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef struct T_event{
    int s_hour,s_minute;//start time
    int f_hour,f_minute;//finish time
}event;
pair<int,int> gettime(event b)// get time when hall is free
{
    pair<int,int>free;
    free.first=b.f_hour;
    free.second=b.f_minute+30;
    if(free.second>=60){
        free.second=free.second-60;
        free.first+=1;
    }
    return free;
}
bool Cmp(event a, event b){
    if(a.s_hour<b.s_hour) return true;
    if(a.s_hour==b.s_hour){
        if(a.s_minute<b.s_minute) return true;
        if(a.s_minute==b.s_minute){
            if(a.f_hour<b.f_hour) return true;
            if(a.f_hour==b.f_hour){
                if(a.f_minute<b.f_minute) return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
int main()
{
    string time;
    int n,k;
    scanf("%d %d",&n,&k);
    vector<event>app(k);
    for(int a=0;a<k;a++)
    {
        cin>>time;
        stringstream stream(time);// get time from string
        stream >>app[a].s_hour;
        stream.ignore();
        stream >>app[a].s_minute;
        stream.ignore();
        stream >>app[a].f_hour;
        stream.ignore();
        stream >> app[a].f_minute;
    //cout<<app[a].s_hour<<app[a].s_minute<<app[a].f_hour<<app[a].f_minute<<endl;
    }
    sort(app.begin(),app.end(),Cmp);
    //cout<<app[0].s_hour<<app[0].s_minute<<app[0].f_hour<<app[0].f_minute<<endl;

    pair<int,int>halls[n]; // first = hour. second = minute. time when hall can be used.
    for(int a=0;a<n;a++){
        halls[a].first=0; halls[a].second=0; // set free time at 00:00
    }
    int possible=0,need=n;
    for(int i=0;i<k;i++){ //check every event application.
        pair<int,int>free = gettime(app[i]); //when hall is free if used by this event.
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){ //check every hall
            int freeh=app[i].s_hour-halls[j].first, freem=app[i].s_minute-halls[j].second;// check if hall free time is earlier or same as event start time
            if(freeh>0 || (freeh==0 && freem>=0)){
                halls[j].first=free.first;
                halls[j].second=free.second;
                possible++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    /*for(int a=0;a<n;a++){
        cout<<halls[a].first<<halls[a].second<<endl;
    }*/
    for(int a=0;a<n;a++){
        if(halls[a].first==0 && halls[a].second==0)
            need--;
    }
    printf("%d %d\n", possible, need);
}
```

[Code-Restaurant](https://ideone.com/5k5cZ4)

Please Help.

Comment: A few comments: The first two lines come highly not-recommended. There's no need to `typedef struct` in C++ `struct event { ... }` is sufficient. I don't think the  `stream.ignore();` are causing you any problems, but I don 't see them being necessary. You're better off picking one of C and C++ style IO and sticking to it.

Comment: I wish I had a an answer for you. The best I can suggest is that you expand your test cases until you find the family of input cases you are missing.